# what is best approach for dataadnotations in blazor client side? when shared project where model is , is missing assembly?

Tags: c#, blazor, data-annotations, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

so i have some blazor clientside project
so as i should i have lets say `person.cs` in shared project so it can be used both in client and server side - by design it is correct place for such class... ?

now  in client side i have `MudBlazor` as component library

so now as they have an option to automaticly set labels on components based on attribute as here
https://mudblazor.com/components/form#automatically-set-labels

so i need to have like

```
sharedproject/person.cs

 public class person{

   [Label("enter name")]
   public string name {get;set;}
  }
```

and it yealds at me because shared project has no idea about this `MudBlazor LabelAttribute`
[image]

so what would be best solution here? install mudblazor in shared project? is it good option ?
or not use this attribute in such cases?
i need this class in both client and server project
creating second 'derived' is option but it will be same class just with the `[labels]` so not best option imho also?

please advise
best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are right, the correct place for DTO classes used by both Client and Server, is a shared project.

Maybe the clean solution is to have 'derived' classes, but it is easiest to install MudBlazor in the shared project. In that case you'll have this dll in you API project but don't need to duplicate all of your DTO classes.

IMHO MudBlazor should give a "Global" configuration where you can define if use their custom attribute "Label" or the generic one "Display", this way it would be possible to use in a shared project the "Display" attribute without the need to install MudBlazor.

That was discussed in those topics:

- https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/pull/5225
- https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/pull/5329

Comment: thanks that does not satisfy me  but is max i can get probably for now ;)

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to use an interface IPerson, with two implementations, one client-side and the other one in server-side.

Something like that

```
public interface IPerson {
   string Name {get;set;}
}


// Implementation in client side
public class Person : IPerson {

   [Label("enter name")]
   public string Name {get;set;}
}

// Implementation in server side
public class Person : IPerson {

   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

That way, you can still have

Comment: so as i wrote - second 'derived' is option but it will be same class just with the [labels] - interface is the same. but the clasess would be same only labels added - is there a better solution then duplicate of the class here and here?

Comment: If you want to use the Label attribute, and to use the same class in front and back, I guess you cannot avoid the reference of MudBlazor in the Shared project. It is not a very bad thing in my guess. While you do not have some weird UI components in Shared, iI think it is okey :)

Comment: i think i can live without this funcionality;P but idea is strange - i will write on their github what They think about that. when i would add it in to shared then server side would also have this dlls Yes? i known that this not the issue but not best idea imho also to have them in api project ;P